# Mapping question related to complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

In what line of the plan $C_W$ is the circle $|z|=1$ mapped using the function $W=√(z+1)$?

How about the mapping of the circles $|z|=r$ using the function $W= z + (1/z)$ and $W= z- (1/z)$

Now,the problem is that there arent examples on how to solve exercises like this in my book (There are examples with mapping but they are very easy) and this is not an university textbook ( I'm preparing myself),so how to do this please? ( Excuse me being forward but I really want to know how to do them)

Comment: For $W = \sqrt{z + 1}$, what are you taking as the branch cut?

Comment: He would have to be taking a cut in the left half plane, wouldn't he? That means it wouldn't matter to us which (because the unit circle is mapped to the right half-plane under $z\mapsto z+1$).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, the answer will, as T. Bongers pointed out, depend on which branch(es) of the square root function you want.  Independently of that issue, though, if a point $w=x+iy$ is on the curve in question, with $w=\sqrt{z+1}$, then $w^2-1=z$ and $z$ is on the unit circle.  So $w^2-1=(x^2-y^2-1)+2ixy$ is on the unit circle, meaning $(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(2xy)^2=1$.  Either it's too late in the evening for me to do algebra or this equation simplifies to $x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2-2x^2+2y^2=0$.

So this equation gives you a curve that includes all possible branches of what you're looking for.  With a reasonable choice of branch, the desired curve will be in the first and fourth quadrants, so you'd want to restrict the equation above to $x\geq0$.

Your other two problems are, in principle, easier, since the functions involved are fractional linear maps (also called Möbius transformations), so they map circles to circles (or straight lines). So you can just take three points on $|z|=r$, see where they are sent by the map, and draw a circle through those points.